# Why HttpClient does not return a 302 code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, http-headers, httpclient

I am working with HttpClient. I tried to call some complete_url using Postman (disable autoredirect func). And the Postman returns Status 302, where I see Location header, which I will call in my next GET method.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Postman works good.

But if I try to call the method using Visual Studio. I got result Status-200, without any header "Location".

Here is my code:

```
        HttpClientHandler handl = new HttpClientHandler();
        handl.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handl);

        HttpResponseMessage respn = await 
        httpClient.GetAsync(resp.completeUrl);
        Console.WriteLine($"-----------{respn}");
```

This screenshot is what .Net returns:

[image]

My question is: why does HttpClient not return Status 302 with Header "Location"?

Comment: Why does a server that isn't described in any significant way do [x], [y] or [z]? That's a tricky question for sure. The only thing we can be sure of is that the requests are different.

Comment: [According to this](https://dev.to/joaofbantunes/using-nets-httpclient-without-following-redirects-21k3) `HttpClient` follows redirects by default. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I tried it. But nothing any changes. Status - 200/